# How to create input elements dynamically from an array with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am creating input elements dynamically. I have an array that has n number of elements. I need to create n input boxes using Jquery and put the value of each element of an array into a separate input box.

I am using the .trigger("click") function to simulate a click. Additionally, I tried looking for solution, but could not find a satisfactory result. Therefore, I decided to put this question. I looked at .map() Jquery function. The .map().get function returns the array from dynamically created input boxes.

Comment: can you show us with what you did so far ?

Comment: @John See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var values = [1, "hello", 1.6, "some other value"];

// the container you want to append the inputs to
var $container = $("#container");

values.forEach(function(value) {
  // create the an input
  var $input = $("<input/>");
  
  // change it's properties (if you want to)
  // $input.addClass("someClass");
  // $input.attr("name", "someName");
  // $input.attr("id", "someID");
  // ...
  // set its value
  $input.val(value);
  
  // append it to the container
  $container.append($input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```